# MudBlazor - MudDatePicker not selecting date on first click

Tags: .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a MudDatePicker that I put in a reusable component.  Here is the code on the parent page:

```html
<MudText>@((MarkupString)paymentsMade)</MudText>
    <div>
        <span>Add Payment</span>
        <MudIconButton Icon="fas fa-solid fa-plus"
                       aria-label="Add Payment"
                       Color="Color.Success"
                       Size="Size.Small"
                       Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                       OnClick="AddPayment">
        </MudIconButton>
    </div>

    @if (_newClaimModelStep1.PaymentsList.Any())
{
    foreach (var payment in _newClaimModelStep1.PaymentsList)
    {

        <Payment PaymentModel="@payment"></Payment>

        <MudIconButton Icon="fas fa-solid fa-minus"
                       aria-label="Delete Address"
                       Color="Color.Error"
                       Size="Size.Small"
                       Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                       OnClick="@(() => RemovePayment(payment))">
        </MudIconButton>
    }
}
```

Code behind for Parent page:

```cs
   public void AddPayment()
   {
       _newClaimModelStep1.PaymentsList.Add(new PaymentInfo());
   }

   protected void RemovePayment(PaymentInfo payment)
   {
       _newClaimModelStep1.PaymentsList.Remove(payment);
   }
```

Here is the markup of the Payment component:

```html
<MudItem xs="12" Class="pb-3">
    <MudDatePicker @bind-Date="@PaymentModel.PaymentDate" Clearable
                    Editable="true"
                    DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                    IsDateDisabledFunc="@((DateTime dt) => dt > DateTime.Now.Date)"
                    Mask="@(new DateMask("MM/dd/yyyy"))"
                    Label="Payment Date"
                    Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                    Margin="MudBlazor.Margin.Dense"
                    For="@(() => PaymentModel.PaymentDate)" />
 </MudItem>
```

Code beind of the Payment component:

```cs
[Parameter]
public PaymentInfo PaymentModel { get; set; } = new();
```

This is the Payment model:

```cs
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(WebResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(WebResource.PaymentDateRequired))]
 [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
 public DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; } // MudBlazor needs this to be Nullable
```

I have shortened some of the code for readability
The issue is when I click the calendar icon of the MudDatePicker, the first click does not set the date in the textbox. I have to then click another date, it then shows, then have to click the original date I wanted.  Typing the date in directly works as expected.

I have used MudDatePickers elsewhere that are NOT in an embedded control and I do not have this issue.  I am not sure why using it this way in a component is causing an issue.  To test this theory, I placed a MudDatePicker directly on the page and it worked as expected.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be happening here or if I have coded something wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Unable to reproduce your error with the code you've posted. It's working as expected. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/Guwdvllbehtzucsl . You probably have code that is not in the question that is causing the behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it has to be something else interfering however I have not been able to find it.  I did find a workaround that does the trick, but I would like to know the real issue.
I just added a callback to the PickerOpened() function of the date picker that calls StateHasChanged().
What I found is that when I clicked, the date was being accepted, but just not showing in the textbox. Calling StateHasChanged() has helped.